# Table Row Filter not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have an admin section in an application that can have a huge number of rows. For convenience I added a "Filter" text box which responds to the keyup event and searches the table and hides the records that do not fit the criteria. It works well in all browsers EXCEPT Internet Explorer which is my company's default browser.

SAMPLE HTML

```
<form class="filter-form">Filter:
        <input name="filter" class="rowFilter" value="" maxlength="30" size="30" type="text">&nbsp;<i class="btnClearBudgetsFilter icon-remove-circle"></i>
    </form>
    <table id="tblCompanyTypes" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>COMPANY TYPE</th>
                <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Corporate</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button class='btnEditRecord btn btn-inverse' data-id='1' data-table='comType'>Edit</button>
                        <button class='btnDeleteRecord btn btn-danger' data-id='1' data-table='comType'>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Development and Construction</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button class='btnEditRecord btn btn-inverse' data-id='2' data-table='comType'>Edit</button>
                        <button class='btnDeleteRecord btn btn-danger' data-id='2' data-table='comType'>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Property</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button class='btnEditRecord btn btn-inverse' data-id='3' data-table='comType'>Edit</button>
                        <button class='btnDeleteRecord btn btn-danger' data-id='3' data-table='comType'>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Property with Dining</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button class='btnEditRecord btn btn-inverse' data-id='4' data-table='comType'>Edit</button>
                        <button class='btnDeleteRecord btn btn-danger' data-id='4' data-table='comType'>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Property with RL</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button class='btnEditRecord btn btn-inverse' data-id='5' data-table='comType'>Edit</button>
                        <button class='btnDeleteRecord btn btn-danger' data-id='5' data-table='comType'>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Property with Dining and RL</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button class='btnEditRecord btn btn-inverse' data-id='6' data-table='comType'>Edit</button>
                        <button class='btnDeleteRecord btn btn-danger' data-id='6' data-table='comType'>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT (The keyup code is in the document.ready function)

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.rowFilter', function(e){
            var term = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

            if( term != ""){
                $('table tbody>tr').hide();
                $( 'table td').filter(function(){
                    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >-1
                }).parent('tr').show();
            } else {
                $('table tbody>tr').show();
            } // end if
        });
```

I created a jsFiddle of the problem and was hoping someone could help me to make this work in IE. To test, type "cor" or "din."

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GvSv8/1/

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: FYI, pseudo selectors won't work in IE < 9.

Comment: Hi found an example that works on ie-9 that might help u...http://jsfiddle.net/prowla/YUtYu/

Comment: Minor note with your code... you likely want to show everything by default and then hide the rows that don't match. (currently in your jsfiddle if you type "3" then backspace (erase it) it shows no results.

Comment: yes, I do but I couldn't figure out how to do that -- just learning jQuery here.

Comment: just put up a condition inside keyup if the box is empty clear the filter...

Comment: @agrothe, what exactly do you mean by psuedo selector?

Comment: HI just little fiddle helps ur filter issue and ie9 issue enjoy works...http://jsfiddle.net/aPLLF/2/

Comment: @jgravois see here http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

Comment: @codebreaker, I edited the post and the jsFiddle following your suggestion and it works great even in IE. Can you make your response an answer rather than a comment so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this below fiddle works in IE and also searches as u expected ...jsfiddle.net/aPLLF/2